# find : process a directory and write results in to found directory

Tags: find

I want to find a directory, apply a command to this and the result should be piped into this found directory.

Assuming that `find -type d` gives

```
.
./cortexa53-crypto-mx8mp
./cortexa53-crypto
./imx8mp_sp
./all
```

I think about doing something like that:

```
find -type d -exec '~/bin/opkg-utils/opkg-make-index {} | gzip > {}/package.gz'  \;
```

the result is as example:

```
find: '~/bin/opkg-utils/opkg-make-index ./cortexa53-crypto-mx8mp | gzip > ./cortexa53-crypto-mx8mp/package.gz': No such file or directory
```

But if I execute that command  (so what is inside `' '`) - it works !?!?

Bonus question: howto avoid finding of `.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to execute anything more complex than a simple command with argument from `-exec`, then do so within an in-line script:

```bsh
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    tmpfile=$(mktemp) || exit
    trap "rm -f \"\$tmpfile\"" EXIT

    for dirpath do
        "$HOME"/bin/opkg-utils/opkg-make-index "$dirpath" | gzip -c >"$tmpfile" &&
        cp -- "$tmpfile" "$dirpath"/package.gz
    done' sh {} +
```

This passes batches of directory paths as arguments to the in-line `sh -c` script.  This short script loops over these paths and for each it will call your utility and write the compressed output to a temporary file.  After writing the file, it is moved into the directory and the loop continues with the next directory.

Note that this would recurse into subdirectories.

To avoid finding `.` use `! -path .`:

```bsh
find . ! -path . -type d -exec sh -c '...' sh {} +
```

Or, with GNU `find` (and some others), use `-mindepth 1`:

```bsh
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '...' sh {} +
```

To avoid recursing into subdirectories, use `-prune` as soon as you've found a directory:

```bsh
find . ! -path . -type d -prune -exec sh -c '...' sh {} +
```

Or, with GNU `find`, use `-maxdepth 1`:

```bsh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '...' sh {} +
```

But if you're only interested in a single directory, without recursion, then you may instead use just a shell loop:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob dotglob

tmpfile=$(mktemp) || exit
trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT

for dirpath in */; do
    dirpath=${dirpath%/}
    [ -h "$dirpath" ] && continue

    "$HOME"/bin/opkg-utils/opkg-make-index "$dirpath" | gzip -c >"$tmpfile" &&
    cp -- "$tmpfile" "$dirpath"/package.gz
done
```

This is essentially the same loop as in the in-line script that `find` executes, but it's a `bash` script and it does needs to carry out some of the work that `find` would otherwise perform (enable globbing hidden names, check that `$dirpath` is not a symbolic link etc.)

Comment: Note that in POSIX `sh`, you can use `~`. You'd want to check the exit status of `mktemp` before carrying on with using `tmpfile`. Switching to ksh93 / zsh / bash... and enabling `pipefail` would allow you detect the failures of `opkg-make-index` (and make the using of a tempfile more relevant). You may want to report failurs in `sh`'s exit status so it's reported by `find` as well. Note that if the last `gzip` fails or the command is interrupted, that will leave a tempfile around.

Comment: Also note that `mktemp` creates a new temp file for you to use safely, but if you rename or delete it, reusing the same path is not safe any longer as some other user could recreate the same file as a symlink to somewhere else. You'd need to call `mktemp` each time in the loop or switch to shells that can create tempfiles (zsh, ksh93...). See also ksh93 `>;` redirection operator here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I just thought about that. Using `cp` rather than `mv` would be better I suppose (or call `mktemp` in each iteration as you suggest).

Comment: Thanks for answering this and the details around! Originally I want to solve that in a single line or at least understand why my attempts fail. But maybe sometime you have to be pragmatic ;)

Comment: @Arno You can definitely put all of that code into a single line if you want, but I don't really see the point of it.  Just use `;` in place of most of the newline characters in the in-line script (not after `do` though).